# There is no display after resuming from sleep

Tags: drivers, display, suspend, hardware

I have a desktop PC. When I suspend and leave the PC unattended for a while, there is no signal on display after resuming from suspend. It happens on both Ubuntu and Windows. Is the GPU faulty here?

I updated BIOS to latest version but nothing changed.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Can you provide any further relevant info on your system?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS. I have a Ryzen CPU and AMD GPU. Is there any useful log I can post here?

Answer (score -1):

I am running a Toshiba Sat Pro which had the same problem...i cured it by entering the bios at boot and disabling the LAN at boot up....now it comes out of suspend everytime